# Codeigniter: Can I return multiple values from the same function?

Tags: codeigniter

I would like to return the query results along w/ the row count without having to run multiple queries. Is this possible in Codeigniter? The following works for returning the query results, but is it possible to also count the number of entries found?

Controller:

```
$data['records'] = $this->item_model->searchItem($item_name);
```

Model:

```
$query = $this->db->query($sql, array($this->user_id, '%'.$item_name.'%'));
return $query->result();
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$bindings = array($this->user_id, '%'.$item_name.'%');

$records = $this->db->query($sql, $bindings)->result();

return array(
    'records' => $records,
    'count' => count($records),
);
```

Then, in your controller:

```
$query = $this->item_model->searchItem($item_name);

$data['records'] = $query['records'];
$data['count'] = $query['count'];
```

Comment: $query does not have a count `$query->result()` does, and you will probably want to send back `$query->result()` as the records...

Comment: @jondavidjohn `$query` already holds the `result`. Look at the end of the first line. Maybe I should rename that variable to `$records`.

Comment: How do i go about "retrieving" this via the controller?

Answer (score 3):

Option one

```
$query = $this->db->query($sql, array($this->user_id, '%'.$item_name.'%'));
$data['result'] =  $query->result();
$data['rows']   = $query->num_rows();
return $data;
```

Option two

```
// model
$query = $this->db->query($sql, array($this->user_id, '%'.$item_name.'%'));
return $query;
// controller
$data['query'] = $this->item_model->searchItem($item_name);
// then you have $data['query']->result();
// and $data['query']->num_rows();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send as many variables from a function as you want ..However plz remember that a function is supposed to do one UNIT of work . thus this rule must not be violated.
we can used contrel structure

> if this {return A;} elseif ()  {return B;} else {return C;}

ALso we can send (bundle) variables in an array and send